# ASP.NET SqlDataSource cached collection

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

Is it possible to programmatically access items in sqldatasource once they are loaded?
Context: sqldatasource is binded to list of checkboxes. When submitted, I have id of selected item, but I also need other information. So if I could acces loaded items in SqlDataSource that would suffice.

i know this is not very clear, I'm new to asp.net and it's **so** counter-intuituve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the sqlDataSource has been setup to Cache the data (`DataSourceMode="DataSet" EnableCaching="True"`) (See [Caching Data with the SqlDataSource Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z56y8ksb.aspx)) then you can select cached items using the sqlDataSource in code like so:

```
DataView dataView = (DataView)sqlDataSource.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments());
DataTable dataTable = dataView.ToTable();
```

The [DataSourceSelectArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datasourceselectarguments.aspx) class provides a means to specify the SortExpression amongst other things.

Hope this helps.